# Excel VBA insert a selection based on dynamic reference

Tags: vba, excel, insert

I have a macro in a report that I run daily. Parts of the macro change the values of the tables. I am trying to insert a specific (unchanged) selection between two values. This needs to be dynamic in the sense that the location of the two values will change every day.

In my code below the two values are:

"Awaiting Retest" and "Gary". My selection should always insert between these two values. When I run the macro I get an error code saying

> Sub or function not defined

and row (marked with two asterisks) highlights.
Would really appreciate any help.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xEndRow As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim G As Long
    Dim H As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim P As Long
    Dim F As Long
    Dim L As Long
    Dim A As Long
    Dim U As Long
    Dim C As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
      xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
      xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
    End If
lOne:

Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Select range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)

If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If xRg.Columns.Count > 1 Or xRg.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox " Multiple ranges or columns have been selected ", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        GoTo lOne
End If

    xEndRow = xRg.Rows.Count + xRg.Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For I = xRg.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If xRg.Cells(I) = "Awaiting Retest" Then
           xRg.Cells(I).EntireRow.Cut
           Rows(xEndRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
        If xRg.Cells(I) = INDIRECT(Address(**Row**() - 1, Column())) = "Awaiting Retest" And INDIRECT(Address(**Row**() + 1, Column())) = "Gary" Then
           Rows.Range("TEST").Select
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
           Selection.Cut
           Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
```

[image: Screenshot of VBA Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for sending the sheet over, in the below I have found the first instance of "Gary" and changed the value of the cell above to "UK Support"
the range is dynamic in the sense that the data can change and this will always go in the line above the first "Gary"

```
Sub Find_First()
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
 FindString = "Gary"
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
     With ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
              Rng.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "UK Support"
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`INDIRECT` is a worksheet function. Worksheet functions are not directly available in Visual Basic.

To use a worksheet functions in VBA (from excel 2010), use the WorksheetFunction object. In your case:

```
xRg.Cells(I) = WorksheetFunction.Indirect(...
```

(As I have Excel 2008, I could not test this. See the documentation.)

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you for this. The WorksheetFunction object did not work for me and gave me the same error (might be because I am on Excel 2010). However I have managed another way to select what I want using: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Gary" And ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Awaiting Retest" Then... However the problem I have now is after the values are confirmed and my unchanged selection is selected and cut I don't know how to tell it to paste in that specific place. The insert I use at the moment just inserts it below itself. Any tips? Thank you